# Rubocop atom linter does not work

Tags: ruby, atom-editor, rubocop, linter

I already installed rubocop globally and checked the version, and also the linter-rubocop, but when I open a ruby file in the editor this error appears in the console:

```
Error running RuboCop Error: -s/--stdin requires exactly one path.
```

I've tried to run manually `rubocop -s <path to file>` and the error continues.

Any suggestion?